# How to stop git hanging on commit in cygwin bash

Tags: git, bash, cygwin

Whenever I type

```
git commit
```

My cygwin bash terminal looks up as if it was waiting for me to finish editing the message in another process but no editor starts.

I get an error

```
"C:/Program (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe": line 0: igncr: invalid option name
```

Which I assume is todo with one of the environment variables I have to try and make cygwin usable.

If I use

```
git commit -m "Some Message Here"
```

Then everything works fine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hanging was caused by git being unable to find my editor when I set the global editor to notepad

```
git config --global core.editor "notepad"
```

Then everything works fine.

By setting the global editor to the windows location of vim

```
git config --global core.editor "c:/APPS/CYGWIN/bin/vim.exe"
```

I was able to run vim and then I could see that there was a lock file as well.